# Is there an optimal way to quantize log-likelihood ratios of an AWGN channel?

Tags: digital-communications, channelcoding, quantization, ldpc

My understanding is that given an AWGN channel and BPSK modulation, an LDPC decoder that uses message passing takes as input log-likelihood ratios $L$ of the following form by Bayes' rule:
$$
L=\frac{P(a=1|r)}{P(a=-1|r)}=\frac{2}{\sigma^2}r
$$

where $a\in\{\pm1\}$, $n\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, and $r=a+n$.

I have been referencing page 22 of [this report](https://ipnpr.jpl.nasa.gov/progress_report/42-184/184D.pdf), which uses a uniform quantizer and mentions that a larger dynamic range results in larger step sizes assuming a fixed number of bits.

Are there other quantization methods that might be better suited to the Gaussian nature of this channel? Said differently, are there quantization methods that better account for $\sigma^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your actual decoder architecture, but if memory serves me right, uniform quantization is optimal for Min-Sum or Sum-Product decoders. (My memory was not fully correct, though. For Message-passing decoders using LLRs with bit widths larger than 4 bits, uniform quantization is indeed approximately optimal. For smaller lengths, you can find better quantizers¹.)

The question is where you put your quantization boundaries: If you have a fixed number of bits for your LLRs, do you quantize the region from, say, $-2\sigma$ to $+2\sigma$, because everything larger is sufficiently "safely" the sign-indicated value, anyway? Or do you have a large code word length, and you want to make sure that in sea of large LLRs, where some represent bit errors, the "righter" ones are
still understood as such?

That's a question of looking your design SNR and your target FER; no general answer or formula is known, far as I'm aware.

---

¹ Geiselhart, Marvin, et al. “Learning Quantization in LDPC Decoders.” 2022 IEEE Globecom Workshops (GC Wkshps), Dec. 2022. Crossref, https://doi.org/10.1109/gcwkshps56602.2022.10008635.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you for your answer!

Comment: I think OP might have been asking whether it would be better to use a non-linear ADC, such as \$\mu\$-law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm)

Comment: @BenVoigt I address that, don't I, in the first sentence!

Comment: Ok, reading again, you did.  I disagree with your intuitive explanation though.  The model for alternative quantization would be "transform, quantize, **inverse-transform**", your explanation is missing the last step.  Of course if you didn't inverse-transform, you would be working with something other than log-likelihood, and break optimality.

Comment: @BenVoigt oh! I need to give that some thought.

Comment: Now, it may well be that uniform quantization is still best... but not for reasons of divergence from LLR

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm currently absolutely in the wrong mindframe, but my memory of writing this answer was this: I had just supervised a bachelor thesis of a student that we tasked with exercising the soft-decision decoder cores on a slightly beefy Xilinx FPGA. The main idea was that these decoders are symmetrical by design, meaning that any codeword would suffice as test for error rates when exposed to varying AWGN. So, pick the all-zero codeword (which conveniently is a valid codeword in any linear code), and add Gaussian noise to it, calculate the LLRs, feed the decoder with these 1/2

Comment: @BenVoigt Now, adding AWGN to zero is simplified by just generating WGN. Turns out BPSK leads to LLRs that are "received value times $2/\sigma^2$", so we needed to generate good, white, highly Gaussian values for usage as LLRs: If noise was not truly white within a reasonable length, a decoder with a channel code of a couple thousand values in length would not show the actual AWGN performance, potentially. But the Normality requirements were even more important; we found that most "Gaussianizing" approaches (to convert uniform numbers coming from his PRNG to normally distributed numbers) 2/N

Comment: @BenVoigt that you find on hardware take shortcuts that do introduce observable bias at BERs that are commonly below 10⁻⁸. At the same time where being true to a correct normal distribution close to zero, we needed to design the optimal "clipping" point (if your received noise value is more than six standard deviations away, it doesn't really matter that much whether it's six or seven or eight standard deviations), so to make best use of our quantized randomness. Sooo long story short, we asked Laurent Schmalen and IIRC he derived that uniformly quantized LLRs are the best. Now, because 3/N

Comment: our LLR happens to be a scalar multiple of the received value, that implies that the same is true for the received value quantization. Now, I must admit I wish I could reproduce that derivation for you here, but I'll be honest and say, I can't. https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.05186 claims "implementation of a message passing LDPC decoder (e.g., min-sum decoder) the messages are usually quantized using a uniform quantization", and that's the best I can do right now. (By the way, the student went on and implemented a 38 GS/s Box-Muller-based AWGN generator+BER-Tester with phenomenally white noise)4/4

Comment: Yeah, reading that ten Brink-chair paper again, uniform is *fairly good*, but not optimal. The difference to what is (probably) optimal just becomes negligible as the number of bits exceeds 4.

Comment: Fixed my answer therein.